# Google web toolkit with Netbeans?

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans

I prefer to use Netbeans as my IDE rather than Eclipse. A few years ago when I looked into Google Web toolkit, there was no good Netbeans plugin for GWT and everyone suggested to use Eclipse. How is the situation now? Is there any better plugin on the market, or is Eclipse the best option?

Comment: Serious GWT programming should never done with netbeans. I had actually liked netbeans better than eclipse - unfortunately, eclipse has a larger plugin/features market. However, ever since Oracle took over, they removed the free-UML tool from netbeans, it has lost all its advantages.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Which free UML tool?

Comment: Did you use `gwt`s built-in tools to create projects and import then to your ide ? I feel like if you get used to the first steps, you can then feel comfort of your ide. YOu can then `.bat` or `.sh`-ize project creation and importing into workspace... [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/9LRQ8PFD2Dg) probably comes handy if you try to follow this method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer Netbeans over Eclipse too. To develop for GWT, I used the following setup steps without installing gwt4nb plugin. Since I use an IDE for code analysis and editing help only, and feel quite comfortable manipulating files and directories in the source tree directly. Though this may not fit your case, I guess for many developers the steps should be good enough because you can treat gwt development just a normal java project.

1. Install JDK, NetBeans-SE. Extract gwt package. I have [a note for gwt-1.7.1](https://github.com/minghuascode/GwtAjax/tree/master/orig/README). If running on a windows 64bit version, install 64bit netbeans and jdk, and also a 32 bit JRE.
2. Copy the Hello sample from gwt directory to a directory out of gwt package directory. Create a project of existing java source code, and put the project under the same Hello directory. Then netbeans will create two files in the Hello directory: nbbuild.xml and manifest.mf, and create its own nbproject directory under Hello. I simply ignore these files.
3. In netbeans "Projects" window, right click on "Libraries" and choose "Add JAR" to add the jar files from the gwt directory.
4. In netbeans "Files" window (not the "Projects" window), you will see the original "build.xml" file that comes with the Hello sample. Edit this file so the "gwt.sdk" points to the location of gwt package directory. On windows 64bit, also add a "jvm" property under "java" task. It shall look like (only jvm=... is newly added):

   <target name="hosted" depends="javac" description="Run hosted mode"> 
       <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode" 
               jvm="C:\\Users\\youhere\\Programs\\jre6.32\\bin\\java"> 
           <classpath>
5. Use "Files" window, click to expand "build.xml" file node. Then right click on "hosted" ant target under "build.xml" and choose "Run Target" in the context menu to build and run the hosted mode.

The ant targets from "build.xml" you usually use:

- "build": Use this to build the javascript.
- "hosted": Use this to build java and start hosted server and browser.

Once the hosted server is started, you can run "build" target to build the javascript and to have the result served by the running hosted server immediately without restarting the server. Use your normal browser to see the javascript version at "localhost:8888". You can set a different port by editing the "build.xml" file.

Usually I copy the Hello sample to a different directory, and use that as a start point of a new project. After that manually edit the files to match the project naming and directory structure.

I also copy the other samples from gwt package to a new directory, then build and run them to use that as a code reference. If you want to also develop the servlet, take a look at the servlet of DynaTable sample and create or copy the files into the same directory structure in your project.

A note about gwt4nb plugin: I installed it but figured out it is too heavy weight for me. With the above manual setup, I can do everything that I need to without any difficulty.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty since your answer is the most complete.. but if you could check it to make sure its still up to date, it'd be great.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I also would like  to request to describe some pros and cons of each IDE on GWT.

Comment: Yes recently set it up with netbeans 7.4 on jdk 1.7. A note about quick compile: The netbeans ant build file is set by "buildfile=" in "nbproject/project.properties". In the build file, if you edit two tags into '<import file="build111.xml" /><target depends="build" name="compile" />', when you hit F11 key it will invoke the "build" target in your build file "build111.xml". If the "build" is substituted by "hosted" it will compile java and start hosted server. Thank you very much for the bounty points.

Answer (score 6):

I would say Eclipse is the best free option. `Intellij IDEA` (paid edition) has also good `GWT` support but it is not as good as `Eclipse`.

I think the only *official* support goes for eclipse, see here : https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download

Based on my personal experience, if you want to have a good integration between `GWT` and your `IDE`, go for `Eclipse`. If you intend to use `Maven`, I also suggest `M2E` http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/

EDIT

Forgot to say the most important thing. `Netbeans` by the way, seems to have a nice support of GWT but I never tested, see : http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html

Answer (score 3):

I am sure this is not the correct and suitable answer. But if you like to trade off, this is just an idea.

```
sudo -i
cd ~/gwt
./projectCreator -ant build -out projects/myapplication
./applicationCreator -out projects/myapplication myapplication.client.MyApp
```

Then, you can import the project ...

1. In Netbeans create a new projects and choose 'Java Project With
   Existing Ant Script',
2. Set Location to the `myapplication` folder created earlier
   Set Build Script to the `build.ant.xml` file created by projectCreator
   Set Project Name to something more appropriate
3. Open the project properties and under Java Sources click Add Folder.
   Select the `projects/myapplication/src` folder and press OK

Please excuse, if you didn't like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar with [Battle for Eclipse and Netbean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839908/netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-development) but you are talking about concern with **GWT**.
So , I think you can choice as you more prefer depends on your experiences. You can do GWT developing in various IDE because I assume **GWT** runs on it's SDK not on IDE . But there has some points of views. Example : easy to generate , test , develop ..etc on each IDE.

I also personally love NetBean due to beautiful GUI :) . But I am working with Eclipse IDE because our team has been developed and configured on it for a long time so we have hard to change IDE (*sometimes very hard to change Eclipse version because we can't imagine new version will more reliable for our projects*).But I don't mean  *Eclipse is the best option* , as I described you may configure your GWT projects on any other IDE also as your experiences via **GWT SDK**.

*"...and everyone suggested to use Eclipse."* . Yes you will see most of sample projects for it were figured with Eclipse IDE. Only aspect for GWT , I think you have chance to choose NetBean IDE without any worries.

You can develop GWT project on NetBean IDE as follow...

> 1.) First off, [download](https://github.com/ksfreitas/gwt4nb/wiki/Downloads) and install the gwt4nb plugin. ( you may have exp for install plugin on NetBean IDE )
>
> 2.) [download](http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html)  GWT SDK and extract it to your specific location.
>
> 3.) create a new **Java Web** –> **Web Application**. Name your application and hit **Next** until you get to                     the **Frameworks** tab. If you have successfully installed the gwt4nb plugin you should see Google Web Toolkit listed. Select the Google Web Toolkit framework.
>
> 4.)  Next, browse to the GWT SDK installation folder. Name your GWT module and hit **Finish**.
>
> 5.) Clean and Build your project.(don't be forgot to wait until successfully finished Build.)
>
> 6.) Run the project, your browser should launch and the button “Click me!” and the text “Hello, GWT!!!” should be visible.

Cheer ! now you can create GWT sample project on NetBean IDE.

You can also create GWT's

- Test Case
- Constants
- Module
- RPC Service
- UiBinder

By right click on **your_project** > **Other...** > **Google Web Toolkit**.

*Have some useful tips for you !*

Comment: isn't the gwt4nb plugin out of date? Last time I checked it, it seemed that it wasn't being updated.

Comment: For example, the current version of gwt is 2.6 as listed here: http://www.gwtproject.org/versions.html , but the latest version supported by gwt4nb seems to be 2.4 : https://github.com/ksfreitas/gwt4nb/wiki/Welcome-to-GWT4NB

Comment: I had tested with GWT 2.5.1 and gwt4nb-2.10.12(that support for gwt 2.5). for gwt 2.6 , i am not sure for it (sorry). But we can't say gwt4nb was out of date cos of it just can support 2.5.1.

Comment: I am sure your  http://gwtproject.org/versions.html link was out of date . pls compare with my link.